# Can't make or receive voice calls anymore

Tags: calls, motorola-moto-g, phone-app

I have a Moto G 2013 (XT1033) with latest Lollipop.

Suddenly I'm unable to make any voice calls. I open the dialer, input the number, press dial and... nothing happens.

Either I'm thrown back to the dialer or I get a "call ended" message instantly after pressing dial.

I also can't receive voice calls, either: they go straight to voicemail. SMS are OK, then I know it's not the SIM card problem.

By adb shell and `dmesg` I saw [those error messages](http://pastebin.com/dYD13AFZ) which make it look like the internal memory is corrupted.

What to do?

Comment: I don't know if your issue is related to mine, but are you able to make calls when you aren't connected to WIFI?

Comment: @mezmo I tried disconnecting from Wi-Fi but didn't work, either.